# Remote booting using Digital IP KVM switch

Tags: boot, remote-access, remote, remote-connection, remote-shutdown

I have a setup where I have a digital IP kvm switch controlling a computer . I can use the switch to remotely shut down this computer . However I cant restart or boot up the computer remotely . In my use case I do require the switch to remotly boot up the computer . Is there a way to do this ? also this is the digital Ip KVM switch I am using https://www.startech.com/ca/Server-Management/KVM-Switches/16-port-Enhanced-Digital-KVM-Switch-over-IP~SV1641HDIE 
Thanks

Comment: Yes I am having trouble finding the restart/reboot option ( the Manual has no information on this )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Remote booting using Digital IP KVM switch**
>
> I have a setup where I have a digital IP kvm switch controlling a
>   computer . I can use the switch to remotely shut down this computer .
>   However I cant restart or boot up the computer remotely.

Based on the below part from the [StarTech SV1641HDIE Enhanced KVM Switch Manual](http://static.highspeedbackbone.net/pdf/StarTech-SV841HDIE-Enhanced-KVM-Switch-Manual.pdf) it appears certain features may be offered separately from the base unit so you may want to confirm (with reseller or vendor support) that you should have the restart/reboot remote server functionality available in the package you purchased with this device through its interface.

> **Purchase Options** 
>   *Certain firmware features may be offered separately
>   from the base unit, in order to reduce the initial cost for the Server
>   Remote Control unit*. 
>   **NOTE:** If you wish to upgrade after the system is
>   in operation, go to the **Manage Firmware** page and scroll down to the
>   section entitled Purchase Options. Look for a unique code, such as:
>   **4-C80C-B960-1-0**. If you provide this code to the technical support
>   department, they can give you an unlock code that will open any
>   feature you request. Types in the code provided, exactly, into the
>   area provided and click **Submit**. The new features opened by the code
>   will be enabled immediately, but you may need to reboot the unit to
>   begin using certain features.
>
> <sub>[source](http://static.highspeedbackbone.net/pdf/StarTech-SV841HDIE-Enhanced-KVM-Switch-Manual.pdf)</sub>

I also read this [here quoted below](https://www.startech.com/ca/Server-Management/KVM-Switches/16-port-Enhanced-Digital-KVM-Switch-over-IP~SV1641HDIE) stating that you need a separate device to scale it for power cycling feature to a power module which would hard boot the devices connected to it I would think.

> ### <kbd>**Overview Tab**</kbd>
>
> **A Scalable IP KVM Solution**
>
> Similarly, the IP KVM switch can be connected to StarTech.com's [8
>   Outlet Remote Power Switch](https://www.startech.com/ca/Server-Management/server-rack-accessories/rack-pdus/8-Outlet-Remote-Power-Switch-RS232-Interface~PCM815SHNA) (PCM815SHNA) to power computers and
>   equipment on and off using an interactive menu.
>
> <sub>[source](https://www.startech.com/ca/Server-Management/KVM-Switches/16-port-Enhanced-Digital-KVM-Switch-over-IP~SV1641HDIE)</sub>

---

### Potential Remote Reboot Workaround Solutions

1. With Windows OSes, you can run the `SHUTDOWN -m \\<ServerName> -r -f` (or `SHUTDOWN -m \\<IPAddress> -r -f`) to force a reboot remotely.

   - You'll want to do this from another machine that can access this with appropriate permissions to run this command.
   - I usually do a `PING -t <ServerName>` right after this until it starts responding to confirm it goes down and comes back up.
2. Once you're connected to the KVM IP interface, you could then navigate the keyboard and mouse on each server from it, and then restart it with the restart options at this level as if you were on the console and needed to restart the server.

### Additional Resources

- [**SHUTDOWN**](http://ss64.com/nt/shutdown.html)

Comment: Hi I contacted the manufacturer there isn't a dedicated reboot button , however through the KVM switch you can remotely control any connected system and reboot it using  the OS specific reboot

Comment: I'm glad to hear **vendor support** confirmed this for you with this product!!